# SQL Server query results in GB

Tags: sql-server

How can you view total space & freespace in GB?

```
SELECT DISTINCT dovs.logical_volume_name AS LogicalName,
dovs.volume_mount_point AS Drive,
CONVERT(INT,dovs.Total_Bytes /1048576.0) AS totalSpaceInMB,
CONVERT(INT,dovs.available_bytes/1048576.0) AS FreeSpaceInMB
FROM sys.master_files mf
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.FILE_ID) dovs
ORDER BY FreeSpaceInMB ASC
```

Comment: Why are you `distinct` ing?

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 1000 again, or 1024 if you want GiB vs GB.